# pass GET through location.href

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using this code in html form

```
 <input name="button" type="button" value="Step 2" onclick="location.href='../ticket/scp/auto.php?dest=../scp/admin.php?t=staff&a=new'"/>
```

when i use print_r($_GET) i get

```
Array ( [dest] => ../scp/admin.php?t=staff [a] => new )
```

whereas i expect to get

```
Array ( [dest] => ../scp/admin.php?t=staff&a=new )
```

how can i fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [*encode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the URI which you pass as parameter, otherwise the browser cannot know know which part belongs to which URI:

```
onclick="location.href='../ticket/scp/auto.php?dest=' + encodeURIComponent('../scp/admin.php?t=staff&a=new')"
```

You can also encode the URI on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the `&` with `%26`. That way it is the urlencoded "&" character, which will be included in the value instead of working as a separator for the passed variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input name="button" type="button" value="Step 2" onclick="location.href='../ticket/scp/auto.php?dest=<? echo urlencode('../scp/admin.php?t=staff&a=new')?>'"/>
```

Comment: Not sure if it works if you encode the *whole* URL. I think not.

Comment: Older browsers won't, newer ones will. But of course it's better be safe than not. Updated codes.